# Java/IntelliJ gui refuses to open - exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

Tags: java, user-interface, intellij-idea

Hi stackoverflow community,

I just started learning how to implement a gui in Java and run into an extremly weird problem on my Windows 10 Desktop. When I tried running my code, it compilied without errors, did nothing for about 5 seconds and then returned the following message:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
```

At first I thougt there is a problem with my code, but I couldn't find out what. While trying to find the error, I noticed that not even something as simple as

```
String test = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("test");
```

works anymore, although it worked just fine recently. Normal console output works fine, too, as older projects proved, it will just exit as soon as any kind of gui appears. I tried running the same code on my linux based laptop and it runs without a problem.

I decided to check the java tools, like java configurator and java info, but they don't start at all. The cursor changed into the loading symbol for 2 seconds, then nothing. Java mission control starts, but crashes as soon as I try to open a JMX console.

I deleted and reinstalled Java JDK and JRE (9.0.4) several times, tried using a different version, reinstalled IntelliJ, even reset Windows to an earlier system image, nothing changed.

The only real answers 3 hours of google searches yielded were something about a broken NVidia Driver (I use AMD, but still upgraded the driver, didn't help) and that this error code is a Windows error code for stack overflow. I tried increasing the memory heap and controlled memory usage by enabling the info bar, but that didn't help either.

After hours of trying to solve this problem, I would be really thankful for any help.

Thanks.

**Edit:**
Per demand, an example (my original code):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PraedikatFrameH extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private JTextField output;
    private JButton palindrom_button;

public PraedikatFrameH(){
    this.setTitle("Palindrom-Check");
    this.setSize(200,300);
    this.output= new JTextField(10);
    this.palindrom_button=new JButton("Ist Array ein Palindrom?");

    JPanel pButtonPanel = new JPanel();
    pButtonPanel.add(this.palindrom_button);

    JPanel outputPanel = new JPanel();
    outputPanel.add(this.output);

    Container palindromPane =this.getContentPane();
    palindromPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
    palindromPane.add(pButtonPanel);
    palindromPane.add(output);

    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

}

public void testJava(){
    String test = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("test");
    System.out.println(test);
}
}
```

And the console output:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4\bin\java" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=50931:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\handm\IdeaProjects\inf_einf_uebung10\out\production\inf_einf_uebung10 PraedikatFrameHMain

Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
```

Comment: Can you post a small example that shows the problem?

Comment: @stdunbar Well, as I mentioned, everything that tries to call some kind of gui causes this to happen. Even if it's just a Main class with nothing in it but a JOptionPane call (see the second code line from my main post).